# Draw a CGRect with Cocos2d

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I'm using CGRect's for hitboxes, and my collisions seem to be a bit off. I want to quickly see where my hitboxes actually are.

I tried a bunch of different approaches but most of them seem to be outdated, or just didn't work for me.

I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7730417/simple-way-to-display-the-borders-of-a-cgrect) already and a bunch of similar approaches.

What is the simplest way to show the borders of a CGRect?

Comment: I also tried making a UIView and setting the frame to the hitbox, but [self addChild:view] doesn't work because apparently a UIView doesn't count as a CCNode.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With cocos2d 2.0, in ccConfig.h there is a CC_SPRITE_DEBUG_DRAW symbol. If you set that to 1, the box will be drawn during the visit cycle.

Comment: I'm not actually usually sprites, I'm using particle emitters. Each object has a particle emitter property as well as a CGRect hitbox property.

Comment: well, go in CCSPrite's code , method <draw> and copy paste the section for drawing the bounding box to your particles object's draw method, with the hitbox CGrect.  just sayin ... :)  you got the code Luke ... use the code

Comment: So my class is called Explosion, it has a CCParticleSystemQuad *emitter, and CGRect hitBox. I'm unclear on exactly how the draw method works. If I add - (void) draw to my class, and put in the code in CCSprite's draw method, it will just draw when I create the object, or do I have to explicitly call the draw method?

Comment: @Kreiri ... yep, if OP's class extends CCNode, or CCParticleSystemQuad (which extends CCNode). @ NMunro : the draw method is invoked by cocos2d for all nodes during the update cycle. So if your class extends a CCNode or CCNode derivative, you should NOT call draw, cocos will do it for you. If you implement a draw in your class, make certain that [super draw]'s functionality is implemented in your draw.

Comment: My class does not extend CCNode. When I call [self addChild:explosion], can I then call [explosion draw]?

Comment: How does this work in V3? see my q: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28523010/drawing-cocos2d-v3

Answer (score 0):

If CC_SPRITE_DEBUG_DRAW, as YvesLeBorg suggested, doesn't suit you, you can override `draw` method in you layer or nodes and draw in that method using helper functions from *CCDrawingPrimitives.h*. Don't forget to call `[super draw]`.

Comment: I've seen this a lot, and I've tried a bunch of different implementations, but none of them actually do anything. No errors or anything, just nothing happens; my hitbox isn't drawn.